# Crosscompiling: exact archictecture for all models

Tags: cross-compilation, arm, cpu, pi-models

I would like to crosscompile some piece of C++ software in a way that I can run on every Raspberry Pi. I am confused about the parameter `-march`.

I've found a great deal of resources recommending to use `armv6zk` to be compatible with all versions of the RPi, while some other mentioned `armv6` or even `armv6z`. See for example:

- [Which CPU flags are suitable for gcc on Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/2046/72884)
- https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/blob/master/configs/bcm2708-ct-ng.config
- [Which gcc compilation flags should use for RPi1 model B ? what is the ABI, architecture and CPU?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38189/which-gcc-compilation-flags-should-use-for-rpi1-model-b-what-is-the-abi-archi)
- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=11629

I then tried to print the architecture used by `g++` on my RPi 1 Model B, and I got an `armv6l`. **Is there even a difference between `armv6`, `armv6z`, `armv6zk` and `armv6l`?**
It is clear to me that

- the earliest RPi have an ARMv6 architecture
- Raspbian is compiled for armv6 for compatibility, while the kernel should be running in the "correct" architecture of the RPi
- All RPis have a hard float and VFP support, thus the remaining part of the compiler parameters are `-mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard`.

**What is the exact architecture parameter for each Raspberry Pi model?**

and

**What is the most specific parameter I can use to be compatible with all models?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe I figured it out after quite some fiddling.

### What is the most specific parameter I can use to be compatible with all models?

[Raspbian FAQ's](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianFAQ#What_compilation_options_should_be_set_Raspbian_code.3F) contain the final answer:

```
-march=armv6
-mfpu=vfp
-mfloat-abi=hard
```

Note that the packages in Debian compiled for the `armhf` architecture are **not the same as in Raspbian: Raspbian has been derived from Debian specifically to contain binaries for `armv6`**; the `armhf` architecture in Debian is compiled for `armv7`, not `v6`.

This is reinforced by [inspecting a binary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24577159/1749822) in Raspbian using `readelf -a -W` from `binutils`:

```
Tag_CPU_name: "6"
Tag_CPU_arch: v6
Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-1
Tag_FP_arch: VFPv2
Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
```

(this is `/usr/bin/g++-6` from the `g++-6` package in Raspbian Stretch). Note that you would get a different answer (namely ARM 7) if you were to inspect the package with the same name in Debian!

### Is there even a difference between `armv6`, `armv6z`, `armv6zk` and `armv6l`?

I figured the suffix `l` [stands for "little endian"](https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=5374), `m`, `z` and `k` are [actual microarchitectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ARM_microarchitectures).

This means that my Raspberry Pi has an actual `armv6`, a [revision 000d](https://elinux.org/RPi_HardwareHistory) with the following features:

```
Model name:            ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
Flags:                 half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls
```

(obtained by running `lscpu`). There is [a bit of confusion](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-commits/Week-of-Mon-20151116/313103.html) on Z and K, but I think the best way to illustrate the difference between these architectures (rather than digging up the official papers by ARM) is looking into [LLVM's definition at `llvm/lib/Target/ARM/ARM.td`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/5023b8235ee390c7d47d4d711e7881e68e66e93a/lib/Target/ARM/ARM.td#L579) for these architectures:

```
def ARMv6     : Architecture<"armv6",     "ARMv6",    [HasV6Ops,
                                                       FeatureDSP]>;

def ARMv6t2   : Architecture<"armv6t2",   "ARMv6t2",  [HasV6T2Ops,
                                                       FeatureDSP]>;

def ARMv6k    : Architecture<"armv6k",    "ARMv6k",   [HasV6KOps]>;

def ARMv6kz   : Architecture<"armv6kz",   "ARMv6kz",  [HasV6KOps,
                                                       FeatureTrustZone]>;

def ARMv6m    : Architecture<"armv6-m",   "ARMv6m",   [HasV6MOps,
                                                       FeatureNoARM,
                                                       ModeThumb,
                                                       FeatureDB,
                                                       FeatureMClass,
                                                       FeatureStrictAlign]>;

def ARMv6sm   : Architecture<"armv6s-m",  "ARMv6sm",  [HasV6MOps,
                                                       FeatureNoARM,
                                                       ModeThumb,
                                                       FeatureDB,
                                                       FeatureMClass,
                                                       FeatureStrictAlign]>;
```

### What is the exact architecture parameter for each Raspberry Pi model?

Now that some light was shed on the acronyms, from [RPi's website](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi):

- Raspberry Pi 1, Model A, B, B+, the Compute Module, and the Raspberry Pi Zero: **ARM11 76JZF-S**, which is part of the [ARM11 family](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.set.arm11/index.html) has `armv6`, in a **BCM2835** SoC.
- Raspberry Pi 2 Model B, rev 1.1: **ARM Cortex-A7**, part of the [Cortex-A family](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.set.arm11/index.html) has `armv7a` in a **BCM2836** SoC.
- Raspberry Pi 2, rev 1.2, and Raspberry Pi 3: **ARM Cortex-A53**, also Cortex-A family, has `armv8a`, in a **BCM2837** SoC.
- Raspberry Pi 3 A+ and B+: **ARM Cortex-A53**, thus `armv8a` in a **BCM2837B0** SoC.

The list above not include the various extra features, such as Thumb.